# static binding and dynamic binding use case

Tags: java

We know static binding occurs for private, static , final and overloaded methods, While dynamic binding occurs for overridden methods.
But what if my method is just public and it is neither static nor overriden and overloaded.

```
public class Test{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("hello!");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.print();
    }
}
```

Can Someone explain me what binding is going to happen for print() as it is neither overloaded nor overridden.

Comment: What's `print`? A method must always have a return type.

Comment: Note that overloaded instance methods are also dynamically bound, just like any other instance method.

Comment: Note that overloaded instance methods are also dynamically bound... Can You please explain it with example ?

Comment: @user2068260 suppose a class Bar has two instance methods foo(int) and foo(String). A class SubBar can override those two methods foo(int) and foo(String). When you call someObject.foo(int), or someObject.foo(String), the method that will be executed depends on the actual concrete type of someObject, just like for any other instance method. The fact that it's overloaded doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Java will use `invokevirtual` anyways to invoke the method (and thats dynamic), whether the method has been overriden or not. It is clearer if you look at the byte code

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: new           #5                  // class Test
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #6                  // Method "<init>":()V
   7: astore_1
   8: aload_1
   9: invokevirtual #7                  // Method print:()V
  12: return
```

line 9 shows invokevirtual. Now the JIT compiler might decide to remove the dynamic dispatch to achieve better performance, [It is one of the used techniques](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques).

Answer (score 1):

You still get dynamic binding here, because the compiler does not know that the method has no overrides. Just-in-time compiler may figure it out and optimize the call anyway, but as far as Java compiler is concerned, the binding to method `print()` is dynamic.

Comment: Note that even if the compiler knew it had no override (because the method is final), you would still have dynamic binding, in case the final method is made non-final later.

Answer (score 0):

You get dynamic binding. The actual `test()` method invoked depends on the actual type of the object not on the declared type of the object. It does not matter that it is not overridden in your example, the method is still virtual and can be overridden.

Note that `main()` has static binding, because (as a static method) the `main()` method depends on the actual type of the class `Test`.